# error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>', After Updating angular from 6.2 to 7.2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

```
import { of as observableOf, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivateChild } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class MasterGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
  constructor(private readonly injector: Injector) {}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (next.data.guards.canActivate && next.data.guards.canActivate.length > 0) {
      return this.executeGuardsCanActivate(next.data.guards.canActivate, next, state);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  executeGuardsCanActivate(guards, next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let start = observableOf(true);
    guards.forEach(guard => {
      start = start.pipe(
        mergeMap(x => {
          if (x) {
            return this.injector.get(guard).canActivate(next, state);
          } else {
            return observableOf(false);
          }
        })
      );
    });

    return start;
  }
}
```

Above is the code which throws error while compiling after angular update from 6 to 7. Any help ?

ERROR in src/app/shared/guards/master.guard.ts(35,7): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
src/app/shared/guards/master.guard.ts(52,7): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.

Routing code

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [MasterGuard],
    data: {
      guards: {
        canActivate: [AuthGuard, UserInformationGuard]
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is inside function `executeGuardsCanActivate`, and this particular line is the problem:

`return this.injector.get(guard).canActivate(next, state);`

Try with below instead:

`return observableOf(this.injector.get(guard).canActivate(next, state));`

Here is a sample code in Angular 9, but I believe it should also work for Angular 7:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mn4h3p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts

**EDIT**

New stackblitz link which works:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mccbhk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts

Comment: Maybe I can help you if you can elaborate on what are you trying to achieve? From the function definition, I understand that you have tried to merge two observable streams, CanActivate and CanActivateChild, but what is the use-case to do it this way. If you can answer this, then maybe I can help.

Comment: i have the code to authenticate at routing using Injectable MasterGaurd, before updating to angular 7 the above code was working fine and authenticating but after updating the same code is throwing error while compiling.
When i applied your fix it compiled successfully but now its not authenticating. Added routing code above

Comment: It looks you have only mentioned the CanActivateChild but haven't implemented it. That's okay. I understood from the routes that there may be multiple canActivate guards under `data` property, which you are trying to drill down and return an appropriate value. Most likely it seems to be a casting issue I have updated the [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mn4h3p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts), see if it helps.

Comment: And this casting issue may be occurring, because Angular 7 has changed the return type of `canActivate` method [see official docs](https://v7.angular.io/api/router/CanActivate#canactivate).

Comment: Please refer to [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mccbhk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts), earlier one is not reflecting the latest changes, I just realized.

Comment: fixed the issue, Thanks !

Comment: Happy to help. :)